# jQuery Remove image in dive and replace new image

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want to remove the image in .cartoon_right and replace new image in the same div, can you help please.

$('.cartoonsmart_right').animate({top:"-300"}, 200,function() {
 $('.cartoon_right') ****/* Remove image in this div and replace new image */**** ) .animate({top: "-400"}, 200, function() { $('.cartoon_right1').removeClass("none");    })   ;
});

Answer (score 0):

with out seeing the rest of your code - you might try something like...

```
$('.cartoon_right').find('img').attr('src', new_image_source);
```

or if you insist on removing that one and adding a new one

```
$('.cartoon_right').find('img').after($("<img src='/images/myimage.jpg' />")).remove();
```

Comment: Hello here is the rest of my code, please take a look for me please.

Comment: Hello SynXsiS here the rest of the code.
delay(3000) .animate({top:"-250"}, 200)
         
      .delay(3000).animate({top:"-300"}, 200,function() {
               $('.cartoon_right') /* Remove image in this div and replace new*/)

      .animate({top: "-400"}, 200, function() {
               $('.cartoon_right1').removeClass("none");    })
         .animate({top: "-400"}, 200, function() {
               $('.head_monkey1').removeClass("none").animate({left:"360","opacity":5},100);
    });

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested? 

If that doesn't work, you could copy your code into http://jsfiddle.net and link it.